# Is it correct to write: "She told her to phone him the morning of the next day."

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is it grammatically correct to leave out **in** and write "She told her to phone him the morning of the next day" instead of "She told her to phone him **in** the morning of the next day"?

If not, why not, and does that rule have a name?

My English teacher (not a native English speaker) tells me it is wrong and that **in** must be in that sentence, but I don't get why.
The task was to transform

> Mrs. X: "Phone me tomorrow afternoon."

from direct into indirect speech. My answer was

> Mrs X. told her to phone her the afternoon of the following day.

Comment: I think native English speakers would be more likely to say "the following afternoon" rather than "the afternoon of the following day".

Comment: I agree. *"Mrs X. told her to phone her **that** afternoon."*, refers to the same day. *" Mrs X. told her to phone her **the following** afternoon."*  refers to the following day.

Answer (score 7):

No, there's nothing grammatically wrong with *call him the morning of the next day*. Arguably, it's semantically ambiguous (as in the old joke 'Call me a taxi.' All right, you're a taxi.') but in reality people accept this to avoid cumbersome phrasing; as Charles said, a native speaker would say *call him the next morning*.  The further away the date is, the more likely it is that *on* will be used: *call me tomorrow* (not **on tomorrow*), *call me the next day* or *on the next day*, but *call me on Thursday* (?*Call me Thursday* is used, but is informal).

Answer (score 1):

it sounds fine to me.  (native American speaker)

Comment: Thank you. :)
My English teacher (no native speaker) tells me it is wrong. The "in" must be in that sentence but I don't get why.

Comment: i think adding the "in" is actually worse...  Better still is "She told her to phone him the next morning"

Comment: However, my teacher is convinced that her version is best. How can I tell her that my version is correct as well and not worth cutting points. I need some strong arguments.

Comment: @IchEben94: Show her this page!

Comment: @ vonjd: I studied one year in the U.S. and she hates when I do not accept what she is criticizing. She thinks that I think my English is better than her's. 
So there probably is no rule to prove that my sentence is right, is there?

Comment: @IchEben94: you could try asking her whether she will be marking the test 'on tomorrow'.  But actually your English probably isn't better than "her's", so best let sleeping dogs lie.  (The difference between native speakers and grammatically-correct speakers is wide in every language; both sides are secretly convinced they alone are right.)

Comment: @Ich: No, I don't think there is any rule that would settle this debate.  BTW, I'd probably include an "in", but change your "of" to "on": _Mrs X. told her to phone her in the afternoon on the following day._ (Though I'd be even MORE likely to say, _Mrs X. told her to call tomorrow afternoon_.) I'd recommend not arguing about such petty prepositional details, and recognize that sometimes such two-letter words are _optional_.

Comment: @J.R. Are you sure you've thought about that?  *In the afternoon on the followng day* sounds impossibly cacophonous to me, and *tomorrow afternoon* refers to a different day.

Comment: @Tim: Hmmm... maybe I meant: _Mrs X. told her to call "tomorrow afternoon."_ (It depends on the context: is this a message that was relayed yesterday, or five minutes ago?) Either way, there's two pieces of information being conveyed: which day to call (tomorrow), and which time of the day to call (in the afternoon). I stand by my main point: whether or not one uses one preposition or two matters little in this case, so long as the information is clearly conveyed. It's more a matter of personal preference than one being "more right" than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two choices offered, that which leaves out *in* seems preferable.  However, if "of the next day" is left off, include the word *in*, or otherwise reword:

> She told her to phone him in the morning.
>   She told her to phone him the next day.

The former of these phrases may be ambiguous regarding if the morning is when she told her, vs. when the call is to be made.  The original choices have the same ambiguity if the narration is completely past tense.  Was it on the morning of the next day after some other event that she told her to phone him, or did she tell someone, "Phone him in the morning"?  The ambiguity can be avoided by using a direct quote.

*Edit (after context was added to question):* One might convert «Mrs. X: "Phone me tomorrow afternoon."» to one of

> Mrs X. said to phone during the afternoon of the next day.
>   Mrs X. said to phone during the next afternoon.
>   Mrs X. said to phone the next afternoon.
>   Mrs X. said to phone in the afternoon.

Phrase "the next day" would be left off if context makes it clear.  "During" can be used as shown and cannot be replaced by *in*.

Comment: The task was it to transform this sentence "Mrs. X: Phone me tomorrow afternoon." from direct into indirect speech.
My answer: Mrs X. told her to phone her the afternoon of the following day.

Comment: @IchEben94: that's *Mrs X asked him to phone her the next afternoon*.

Comment: @IchEben94: It was unclear that the task was that. You should clarify this in the question. For now, I decided to upvote jwpat's answer.

Comment: I know I expressed myself a little complicated with _the afternoon of the following day_ but still, it is not wrong I suppose.

Comment: -1 because your point about "ambiguity" is misleading. All variations of *"someone requested some action at some time"* are inherently ambiguous. Only context can tell you whether the time specified refers to when the request was made, or when the action should take place.

Comment: +1. Very nice. This explains why the English teacher got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To make it absolutely clear, English uses *on* with days, *in* with months.

*Weekend* takes *on* in Am. Eng.; *at* in Br. Eng. but decreasingly so; and perhaps *over* suggesting a longer event over the weekend.

Somteimes we say *for* with holidays: *What are you doing for Christmas?*

Comment: But it also uses *in* rather than *on* with afternoons and mornings. So if you want to use a preposition in the OPs sentence, it would be "in the morning of the next day" and not "on the morning of the next day". I don't see how this answer is relevant.